# LINQ statement All checks syntax problem

Tags: c#, linq, c#-3.0

I'm trying to figure out why it does not liking my checks in the All():

```
itemList.Where(x => itemList.All(x.ItemType != ItemType.Test1 && x.ItemType != ItemType.Test2)).ToList();
```

> `The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.All<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,bool>)' cannot be inferred from the usage.`

UPDATED: The original intent here is to give me my list back, filtering out those items where the criterial in the All() match.

So filter out those items in the list where their Item.Type is not this or that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't provided a lambda expression - what are you wanting to do with each item in `itemList` in the inner part? It should be something like:
    itemList.Where(x => itemList.All(item => x.ItemType != item.Test1 
                                     && x.ItemType != item.Test2)).ToList();

Note the "item => " part.

It's unusual to use the same collection again within an `All` method though... could you give us an idea of the bigger picture?

EDIT: It's not at all clear that you need to call `All` at all. What's wrong with:

```
itemList.Where(x => x.ItemType != ItemType.Test1 && x.ItemType != ItemType.Test2)
        .ToList();
```

? I think you may be a little bit confused about what `All` is for - it tests whether *all* the items in the given collection match the given condition.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed I could use All like this...as I have used it before for filtering out a list based on some conditions in the past for another scenario.

Comment: hmm, I'm getting nothing back in the list: MyList items = items.Where(x => x.ItemType != ItemType.Item || x.ItemType != DispType.Comment).ToList() as MyList;  MyList is just a custom object that inherits from List<MyObject>

Comment: Well the list that's being returned isn't going to be an instance of MyList, is it? It's just going to be an instance of `List<MyObject>`. If you want an instance of `MyList`, you'll have to build one.

Answer (score 1):

The [`All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) method needs a `Func<T, bool>` predicate as an argument. Your code doesn't have one.

It's not clear exactly what your code is meant to do, so it's difficult to suggest any more specific fixes.